# If regresa False cuando la condición si se cumple

Tags: java, condiciones

estoy haciendo un programa en Java y hay algo en lo que llevo horas tratando de solucionar:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El System.out.println esta imprimiendo la condicion que se pide en el IF, como se ve en la parte inferior de la imagen, la condicion se esta cumpliendo, pero aún asi el IF esta retornando false y no esta entrando ¿Alguien sabe que esta ocurriendo aquí y como solucionarlo?
PS: El Array objRec es del tipo String y finalObject es del tipo Double, es por eso que ocupo toString()

Comment: Mm y en que parte esta el else?

Comment: Que estas tratando de hacer con ese finalObject,si estas tratando de con comparar strings lo ideal es hacerlo con un equals

Comment: Gracias, cambiando el if a esta linea (objRec[i][0].equals(finalObject.toString()) soluciono mi problema, error de principiante supongo, muchas gracias!

Comment: No problem crack